# How can I view passwords stored in PGAdmin 4?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I'm using PGAdmin 4 v6.4 on my mac. I have a master password set and a number of passwords saved for databases so I can log in without needing to type the individual passwords each time. How can I view these saved passwords? In previous versions, it seems they were simply stored in a plaintext file somewhere, but that no longer seems to be the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pgAdmin4 stores all the saved server information in a SQLite3 file called pgadmin4.db

> On Windows, we always store data in %APPDATA%\pgAdmin. On other platforms, if we're in server mode we use /var/lib/pgadmin, otherwise ~/.pgadmin

All saved server credentials can be found in the server table.

The passwords are encrypted using AES CFB8. You can decrypt them with your master password by referring to this [file](https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/blob/master/web/pgadmin/utils/crypto.py)